# Is it possible that a fare is shown on ITA Matrix but not available to agencies?

Tags: fares, ita-matrix

I got a fare on ITA, but the agencies that I contacted say they don't have one of the legs available? Basically the class shown on ITA is not available on travel agents.

I double-checked all the parameters. Even the city of the origin.

I am seeing the fare for more than one week now and I've been inquiring agencies since I saw it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible for this to happen.

I think [Google themselves say it best](https://support.google.com/faqs/faq/1739451?rd=2#2760137):

> Please also know that the data we show can unfortunately change at any time in any direction. We generally have a very high accuracy rate, and we update our data as fast as anyone in the industry and faster than most. That said, these changes are determined by the airlines, and we do not know when or how the data will change. We're always working with the airlines to improve the quality of our search results, but it may be possible that a specific fare you see is no longer available.
>
> If you're unable to book a particular flight at the price you saw on our website, please [let us know](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/matrixandonthefly).

Comment: Thanks!! But that's strange than, specially because I am seing this fare for more than one week now.

Comment: I think Google definitely will want to know about that, so that they can find the problem and fix it!

Comment: Maybe not every agency is able (or willing) to sell every fair.

Comment: Airfare rules are extremely complex and constantly changing.  The search algorithms employed by engines like ITA Matrix do not always take them all in.  It is entirely possible that one leg has a fare rule that hasn't been programmed into ITA's data, but is showing on the travel agency's CRS.

Comment: @Tom I thought ITA was actually the engine of most of those agencies?!

Comment: @Aganju they showed me the screen. It reported that the flight was closed for that class. Actually only first class was available. The funny thing is that if you buy only that flight separately on the company the fare is available.

Comment: Most travel agencies are tied to one of the major CRS - Sabre, Amadeus, etc, but some agents may also access ITA as a "second opinion".