# Help with booking a flight on ITA Matrix

Tags: air-travel, bookings, flight-search-engines

I found this itinerary ITA Matrix:

[image: itinerary]

However, I am having trouble booking it online. I've used aggregators Kayak and Hipmunk. Both display the itinerary but they show a much higher price.

Kayak:

[image: Kayak]

Is there a place online where I can book this itinerary?

Alternatively, is there any travel agent I can call and have them book it?

I've read some other posts where users suggested to change the sales city, but my sales city is the same for all searches (Boston).

Comment: You have set up a two day stopover in IST on the return. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes, that was intentional, so I could see the city for a bit.

Comment: Related: [Are there “traditional” travel agents receiving requests online for ITA fares?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65974/32134) and [How can I book a flight plan found on Matrix Airfare Search?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21671/32134). And note the comment on TK prices in my answer to the first Q.

Answer (score 8):

According to [expertflyer](http://www.expertflyer.com) (free trial available), there is U class availability on the TK82 and TK72 outbound on August 12 but there is no U class on either the on August 22 or the TK81 on August 25. On the TK73 the lowest class availability is showing as S (9 classes above U) on August 22 and on August 25 the lowest availability is E which is 7 fare classes above U.

The problem appears to be married segment availability as U is available on the TK73 CAN-IST segment if booked individually, but not available on IST-BOS nor CAN-IST-BOS. ITA is known to have problems in this area.

Comment: Would booking it more separately lead to a lower fare?

Comment: @SarahP The only way I can see you getting the inbound U availability is an open jaw BOS-IST-CAN//CAN-IST followed by an IST-BOS one way. The IST-BOS one-way is going to be very expensive though.

Comment: When I browsed on the airline's website, it shows the opposite. Economy restricted is available on inbound, but not outbound. What does that mean? [http://imgur.com/a/GaO5N](http://imgur.com/a/GaO5N)

Comment: @SarahP The airline itself can show availability it doesn't show on a GDS. There is something weird going on here because I can't even price a straight BOS-CAN return on matrix at all

Comment: Yeah, if I simply search BOS-CAN return, it doesn't show. But if I specify a layover in IST, then it shows. Try entering [this](http://imgur.com/a/6H4Zy) on Matrix. Does it show up for you?

Comment: @SarahP I already tried that and it didn't work even if I select to ignore availability.

Comment: That's odd. What does it give you when you try it? It also works on Kayak, albeit at a higher price. [https://www.kayak.com/flights/BOS-CAN/2016-08-12/2016-08-22](https://www.kayak.com/flights/BOS-CAN/2016-08-12/2016-08-22)

Comment: @SarahP Sorry, yes it does show if I specify IST both ways. It has the same problem in that it's promulgating single segment availability to the married segments again.

Answer (score 5):

Economy appears to be sold out on your outbound itinerary. When I try to book this itinerary at Turkish Airlines directly, *including* your two day stopover in IST, the lowest class it offers for BOS-IST and IST-CAN is premium economy. This may explain the difference in price.

And, it certainly is possible for [data in Matrix to be out of date or inaccurate](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66174/3221). There might have been an economy fare available 30 minutes previously, and someone got the last seat in that block before you did.

Answer (score 4):

It is absolutely possible that ITA Matrix shows sold-out fares; I've had it happen to me multiple times before.

I just tried the same itinerary with the Priceline link on [BookWithMatrix](https://bookwithmatrix.com/) ([link to itinerary](https://bookwithmatrix.com/7cc806285dd6780b43501f81265ceab2)), which usually works, and it returned an even higher price, so I'd say it's probably sold out.

[[image: Price on Priceline, accessed through BookWithMatrix]]

Comment: Could it be possible that priceline not searching deep enough?