# Unable to book same price ticket as shown in matrix.itasoftware.com

Tags: air-travel, airlines, bookings, ita-matrix

How to book the tickets dispalyed by matrix.itasoftware.com
When I search through any ticket booking site, the prices differs a lot. Even the airline website does not show the same.

Comment: Also [Help with booking a flight on ITA Matrix](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76308/32134), [Are there “traditional” travel agents receiving requests online for ITA fares?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65974/32134) and [How can I book a flight plan found on Matrix Airfare Search?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/21671/32134)