# Purchase tickets, Prague to Brazil, but using Bank Transfer

Tags: europe, travel-agents

I am Brazilian in Brazil, but I need to buy a flight ticket for a festival participant that should come from Prague to Brazil.

The question is: Where can I find some system or travel agent based in Europe that could accept bank transfer?

Note that for example expedia.com does NOT accept bank transfer.

So does anyone know

(1) an online flight service (like expedia) that DOES accept bank transfer?

(2) a physical flight shop in Europe - perhaps Prague - who does accept bank transfer?

Comment: i don't have any facts on it, mts!   note Max that KLM, for example, has bank transfer https://www.klm.com/travel/us_en/plan_and_book/booking/payment/index.htm

Comment: @JoeBlow Expedia doesn't accept bank transfer :(

Comment: @JoeBlow I would like some option like Expedia (to book in all companies) but that could accept bank transfer.

Comment: Have you considered a regular travel agent, one with an office and people you can talk to?

Comment: Business accounts can generally have bank cards as well. There's no requirement to pay everything by bank transfer.

Comment: Hi mts, that begs the question - I wouldn't have a clue of a "well known, reputable 'human' flight shop, in Europe or CZ particularly" .... who knows one?!?!

Comment: Max, a random example of a very well know, large, absolutely safe and reputable flight shop in Europe is: www.flightcentre.co.uk.  They are incredibly helpful; perhaps just call and ask and they will either do it or tell you who to use.

Comment: The expedia idea was great, if it could accept bank transfer would be great. Let's see if someone will know about similar service. Maybe the question will be the same as "how to buy a flight (by distance)  without a credit card in Europe".

Comment: Question got much better, but don't you have anyone based in Brasil? I don't see why you would make the "detour" to an agent in Europe. If you do however insist, try talking to the guys listed in my answer here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65974/32134

Comment: I going to reopen the question. It is much better know, and neither opinion based nor a shopping question. The OP asks for online services or flight shops that accept bank transfers.

Answer (score 2):

Not the exact answer to your question but note that

- KLM
- Emirates
- Air France in particular like bank transfers

definitely accept bank transfer as payment as a matter of course. (It is common for business travel, particularly from certain regions.)

HOWEVER unfortunately they are fussy about the country-pair involved; you'd have to check by phone in each case. (As a general comment, AF is "more loving of bank transfers" so it may be your solution.)

---

Note that as it happens the best way to get from Prague-SP is:

1st - SWISS (unfortunately they do NOT, I believe, accept bank transfers.)

2nd - AF.  (Tragically you have to change in CDG, but that's life. By coincidence this is literally the least time Prag-SP journey.)

3rd - Emirates (a few hours longer), Lufthansa

4th - KLM

Comment: These are great suggestions because both airlines fly Sao Paolo-Prague with a stop somewhere in between (but the same airline flies the whole itinerary.)