# Is there aggregator flight search allowing full time filter

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

My requirement is quite simple, but none of the aggregators I know about allows it.

So I need to be in Kyiv in time for work at 9am Monday, and I can leave Tallinn any time starting from 6am Sunday.

Which flight search engine would allow me to filter based on a time period within 2 days.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 ways to achieve this, both of them are not completely automatic and are based on assumption that your time period is only 2 days.

First way is to use [ITA Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/), which allows you to choose 2-5 days for both departure and arrival:

[image: dates selection in ITA Matrix]

Unfortunately, preferred times are rather limited there, so we won't use them. Instead you can use "Time bars" view and visually filter out some flights (red lines are mine):

[image: time bars view]

However, you cannot buy a ticket at ITA website, so you will have to buy it somewhere else (e.g. other flight search website, airline website, travel agents).

Second way is to enumerate all possible combinations:

1. Depart on Sunday, arrive on Sunday;
2. Depart on Sunday, arrive on Monday;
3. Depart on Monday, arrive on Monday.

That is you do 3 searches instead of 1.

Most flight search sites allow to filter out flights by time (for example, [Google Flights](http://google.com/flights)), so you can enforce 6am departure on Sunday or 9am arrival on Monday in corresponding searches.

Comment: ITA matrix is nice. Do you know why the list an prices from Kayak and ITA Matrix are different?

Comment: #Gleb, as @Calchas wrote in [Are there “traditional” travel agents receiving requests online for ITA fares?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65974/):  "[The ITA matrix] uses some very sophisticated pricing algorithms to find a very good price.". For booking a ticket from ITA you can have a look at [How can I book a flight plan found on Matrix Airfare Search?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21671/how-can-i-book-a-flight-plan-found-on-matrix-airfare-search) (namely, [Hipmunk](https://www.hipmunk.com), but it is unclear whether it still works).

Answer (score 4):

You mean time-based faceted search? A few of them do it.

- On [kayak.com](http://www.kayak.com), you can do a search from A to B. Then on the search results page, look on the left side. You can set time boundaries for your departure time / arrival time for each leg of the flight.
- On [hipmunk.com](http://www.hipmunk.com) you can search, then sort by takeoff/landing time for your flights, and see at a glance when they leave/land. You can also use the slider at the top of the results to set the boundary times you require.

Comment: Kayak allows only time of day restriction, not time-date combination.
For me arrival any time on Sunday AND Monday before 9am fits, and I can't do that on Kayak.

Comment: @Gleb I see what you mean. I guess you kinda can, just involves checking it twice, by moving the sliders. But it's not as perfect.